# Why does fpdi crop the pdf page?

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

So, I'm using `fpdi`, version 1.2 to add some little mark to every page in my document. Here is my code:

```
public static function markPdf($file, $text){
    define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');
    require_once('fpdi/fpdf.php');
    require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');
    try{
        $pdf = new FPDI();
        $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
        for($i = 1 ; $i <= $pagecount ; $i++){
            $tpl  = $pdf->importPage($i);
            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpl);

            // Here you can see that I'm setting orientation for every single page,
            // depending on the orientation of the original page
            $orientation = $size['h'] > $size['w'] ? 'P':'L';
            $pdf->AddPage($orientation);
            $pdf->useTemplate($tpl);

            $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(150);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
            $pdf->Cell(0,0,$text,0,1,'R');
        }
        $pdf->Output($file, "F");
    }catch(Exception $e){
        Logger::log("Exception during marking occurred");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And everything works just fine, except for one little issue: when I have a document with first page in landscape orientation, all pages in generated document are cropped from the bottom and right (if the first page is in portrait mode, everything goes just fine, even if following pages are in landscape mode).
The question is obvious: what's wrong with this function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last argument to `useTemplate()` specifies whether to adjust page size.  It defaults to `false`, but we want it to be `true`.

Change this call:

```
$pdf->useTemplate($tpl);
```

to (for older fpdf versions):

```
$pdf->useTemplate($tpl, null, null, $size['w'], $size['h'], true);
```

or (for newer fpdf versions):

```
$pdf->useTemplate($tpl, null, null, $size['width'], $size['height'], true);
```

Consider updating all `fpdf`-related libraries (`fpdf`, `fpdf_tpl` and `fpdi`) to the most recent versions - that's important, too.

P.S.: When pushing new version of `fpdi` on testing server, I found that it doesn't work with relatively old versions of PHP interpreter - it does work with version 5.3.10, but it can't work with 5.3.2 or older.  So, make sure that you have an up-to-date PHP version too.

Comment: Thank you for this. This helped me so much you have no idea.

Comment: When I use this code, it add very big margin at the right and bottom side of the PDF, could you help me with this ? I have PDF that have different size of page in one document

Comment: Thanks, it saved a lot of time.

Comment: Wow, I totally did not expect my answer to still be relevant after 6-7 years. :)

Comment: @aga 10 years, and still going strong